# Minecraft PE Connect to a Mac?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

There have been several post on this subject, but most are dated 3-4 years ago, or more. I have recently installed Minecraft on my iMac. My sons have it installed on their iPads. Is there any way for them to join the world I've created on the iMac?

I didn't think this was a duplicate question, as the ones I had found were old. Further, there appeared to be conflicting answers in those that I did find. Thus, my reason for this post was to get an August 2016 clarification.

Comment: Although with some sites it might be reasonable to assume that old posts are always out of date, on this site old posts are expected to be updated when the answer changes. Because of that (and to encourage that to happen!), we always only ever have one page about the same question instead of new posts every few years about the same question. (Thank you for asking the duplicate question though—having multiple duplicates linked together makes it easier for other people to find the main question post and its answers!)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie (Just pinging because you gold-hammered.) VTRO per [Duplicate Questions: A New Look](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11865/) and [Duplicate Questions: A Trial](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11895/).

Comment: @Schism Right, thank! I'd seen that, but forgot about it. I'll reopen this, since the other question doesn't actually (yet?) help this asker. Worst case (and not terribly “worst”) they can be merged later.

Answer (score 1):

Currently you cannot join a Minecraft PE world on a mac. If you have windows 10 you can download Minecraft Windows 10 Edition. MC Windows 10 edition support

Minecraft Windows 10 Edition:

> Play online and local multiplayer with other Pocket Edition players thanks to a free update, due to arrive soon after launch.

https://mojang.com/2015/07/announcing-minecraft-windows-10-edition-beta/

The only thing that supports mcpe

Comment: Well, it gets more involved than this. After some reading, I did find out that it simply isn't gonna happen with my Mac. So, I installed the new Windows 10 Edition Beta of MC on a Win 10 computer. Unfortunately, even though Multiplayer and Broadcast to LAN are turned on, none of our three iPads running MCPE can see this world, nor does another Win 10 computer on our LAN. So, I'm at a loss to determine why these Win 10 systems are not seen by each other OR the PE version. Any ideas?

Comment: That is weird, have you updated MCPE on the ipads? either that or your internet connection is too slow :/

Comment: Yes, MCPE in all three iPads is up to date. The Internet connection is quite fast, and all three iPads are able to join one another's worlds. It is just the two Windows 10 machines that seem stuck in their own environment. They cannot see each other, they cannot see the iPads, and the iPads cannot see them. Typical Windows cr@p, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have heard, potpotsie made a server plugin that allows people from PE and PC to play together. You can check that out. If that does not work, I know the Win10 edition you can play with your sons on a local network, but Mac users are stuck in the Java Minecraft world.

Comment: Could you possibly provide a link to this server plugin? It will make your answer more complete.